# coexistance for the longest prefix match

Tags: routing, ipv4, ip-forwarding-table

For example, can 128.92.128.0/17 and 128.92.128.0/18 be contained in one forwarding table together? Or the first one must be changed to 128.92.192.0/18? Because the other half will go to the second prefix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both routes would be installed into the active routing table and the more specific route would win if it was relevant to the packet being routed.

128.92.128.0/18 will be installed but so will 128.92.128.0/17 as the /18 doesn't cover all of the /17.

If you had static routes configured like this...

```
128.92.128.0/18 VIA x.x.x.x
128.92.128.0/17 VIA z.z.z.z
```

You would have the following results in the active table.

```
128.92.128.0 - 128.92.191.255 will be routed via x.x.x.x
128.92.192.0 - 128.92.255.255 will be routed via z.z.z.z
```

The only way the /17 route wouldn't show up in your routing table is if you had something like this going on for static routes.

```
128.92.128.0/18 VIA x.x.x.x
128.92.192.0/18 VIA y.y.y.y
128.92.128.0/17 VIA z.z.z.z
```

Your active table would look like this.

```
128.92.128.0 - 128.92.191.255 will be routed via x.x.x.x
128.92.192.0 - 128.92.255.255 will be routed via y.y.y.y
```

Since you have all of the /17 covered by more specific /18 routes the /17 drops out of the active routing table.

Answer (score 6):

IP forwarding tables are commonly stored in an [m-trie](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/7149216.html), which is a 256-way [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

If the forwarding table was implemented as a 256-way m-trie, then 128.92.128.0/17 would contain the mtrie entries for 128.92.128.0/18... although these two routes could easily go to different IPv4 next-hops, since IP routing works on the principle of longest-prefix-match wins.

This is a simplified view of an mtrie for 128.92.128.0/17...

[image: 128.92.128.0/17 mtrie]

This is a simplified view of an mtrie for 128.92.128.0/18 (which is contained inside 128.92.128.0/17)...

[image: 128.92.128.0/18 mtrie]